# Guide to cardinals and ordinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I'm looking for a short textbook concerning cardinal and ordinal numbers (their definition and arithmetic). It may be rather formal or complicated, but shall contain the necessary methods for a mathematician. Is there such a guide and which one you can recommend?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSSsZLTMDq0

Comment: @Elmar Guseinov: Check out "Naive Set Theory" by P. Halmos (ISBN-13: 978-1781394663) & "Classic Set Theory: A Guided Introduction" by D. Goldrei (ISBN-13: 978-0412606106). Both are pretty good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Set Theory by Thomas Jech, chapter 2 and 3. Goes into good detail. The book as a whole is great for learning set theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Set Theory : An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by Kenneth Kunen.